# cannot locate element within a web page using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I just want to write a simple log in code for one website. However, I think the log in page was written in JS. It's really hard to locate the elements with selenium. 
The web page I am going to play with is: 
"https://www.nike.com/snkrs/login?returnUrl=%2F"

This is how the page looks like and how the inspect element page look like:

[image]

I was trying to locate the element by following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time 
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.nike.com/snkrs/login?returnUrl=%2Fthread%2Fe9680e08e7e3cd76b8832684037a58a369cad5ed")
time.sleep(5)
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe")) 
elem =driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ce3feab5-6156-441a-970e-23544473a623']") 
elem.send_keys("pycon") 
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN) 
driver.close()
```

This code return the error that the element could not find by `[@id='ce3feab5-6156-441a-970e-23544473a623'`.

I tried playing with frames, it seems does not work. If I went to "view web source" page, it is full of JS code.

Is there a good way to play with such a web page with selenium?

Comment: I am sorry that my code is not well   formatted.

Comment: If you know that your code is not well formatted, why didn't you fix it? ;)

Comment: WOWOWOWOW, how did you do that, i tried, and i thought I could not modify it after I post it....I need to learn how to use this website. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the code :

```
elem =driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ce3feab5-6156-441a-970e-23544473a623']")
```

to

```
elem =driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@type='email']")
```

Comment: It works!! great thanks!! I am a new bird here, so happy to get answer to a problem that confused me for a week...

Comment: Hi Bud, I met a new problem. With the same link above, click "join now" will enter a sign up page. There is one element named "date of birth". Actually, i am able to locate the element, however, i cannot use element.send_keys("12081922") to fill that line. There was not error with the code, just failed to fill the form correctly. I also tried element.click() first, then element.send_keys("12081922"), no error, but failed to fill the form.

Comment: @Luke - could you please initiate that in a different thread, would be better to understand. Seems like its not dependent on this anyhow.

Comment: Sure, may I trouble you to look at my another problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37705631/failed-to-submit-a-form-using-python-selenium-without-a-manual-mouse-click

Answer (score 0):

My guess (and observation) is that the id changes each time you visit the page. The id looks auto-generated, and when I go to the page multiple times, the id is different each time.

You'll need to search for something that doesn't change. For example, you can search for the `name` attribute, which has the seemingly static value "emailAddress"

```
element = driver.find_element_by_name("emailAddress")
```

You could also use an xpath expression to search for other attributes, such as `data-componentname`:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@data-componentname='emailAddress']")
```

Also, instead of a hard-coded sleep, you can simply wait for the element to be visible:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.nike.com/snkrs/login")

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, "emailAddress"))
)
```

Comment: Hi Bryan, I met a new problem. With the same link above, click "join now" will enter a sign up page. There is one element named "date of birth". Actually, i am able to locate the element, however, i cannot use element.send_keys("12081922") to fill that line. There was not error with the code, just failed to fill the form correctly. I also tried element.click() first, then element.send_keys("12081922"), no error, but failed to fill the form.